# Firebase - Determine rank of specific user by score

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

In order to give you some context, first take a look at my database structure in firebase:

```
user-list {
    user {
        name: "xy",
        score: "xy"
    }
    mooare users...
}
```

Now, currently, I have my DB in Firestore Beta, but I don't care if I have to migrate back to the Real Time Database to make this work, since both models work for my application.

**The problem**

If the user has played through the game (which can happen quite often), his rank will be displayed to him. My current approach is to somehow query/assign the users rank based on his score. For that i just order the whole database (1M+ records) aaaaand thats the point where I don't know any further.

The thing is, how on earth am I going to do that? I have read countless stackoverflow posts and searched countless websites and no "solution" helped me yet. The thing is, I have the following requirements to fullfill: Do a query which...

1. is cost effective a.k.a doesn't force me to live under a bridge for the rest of my live
2. is quite fast on the client side
3. is real time

Furthermore my score is variable. Meaning, that it can range from 1 to infinity, which doesn't really remove complexity either.

The most promising approach is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378543) that I found on one of my hopeless hunts for answers. Tough it is only vaguely descriped so that doesn't really help.

I know that's quite a lot to ask, with quite a lot of requirements, but is anyone able to help me with this mountain of a problem?

Comment: Have a similar structure as you with the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I understand your question has slightly different requirements, but perhaps my answer here can give you a push in the right direction (also for @Dror): https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926755/2924905